# How to post to Google+ Business Page from Google+ Profile?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

I'm the admin of a Google+ Business Page. If I post to it from my Google+ profile by choosing it from the circle drop-down menu, the posting shows as *John Doe Shared a post with you* instead of normal post entry.
Is there a way to post to a Google+ Business Page from a Google+ Profile?

Comment: It looks like google has changed how this is done. It isn't allowing me to post my answer here (as I don't have a high enough reputation on this stackexchange site), but I've posted it here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102407/how-do-you-post-to-a-google-page-as-that-page/102408#102408

Comment: @CpnCrunch: A better option would have been to flag the question and request that "Protection" be removed.

Comment: Actually, it's due to my lack of karma on this particular stackexchange, so I'm disallowed "by design" from answering questions, which IMO is pretty dumb and counterproductive. I have a high karma on stackoverflow. Never mind, it's all sorted out now (albeit you got the karma for my answer, so the problem of me not being able to answer questions remains).

Answer (score 2):

The "new" Google+ just recently launched. To post *as* that page, such as a status post, here are the steps:

1. Log in to G+ with your usual Google Account
2. Click your profile photo in the upper right
3. The drop-down that appears will include your G+ pages; click the one you want to use
   [image: account/page selector]
4. You're now effectively using G+ *as* that page; when you post it'll show the page's name
   [image: posting a status message as a page]

Comment: There is no "pages" link any more.

Comment: I have re-written my answer with the new process.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that sharing a Google Plus Brand Page to Google Plus Profile Page (same owner) results in post being 'Shared Privately'.  Don't know who sees it in this case.  Presumably only followers who also share the Brand Page as well as the Profile.  Had not tried this before.

Answer (score -1):

Here is more about the Google+ Pages:

https://support.google.com/plus/topic/3052532?hl=en&ref_topic=3049734

Manage the Pages via the Dashboard:

https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3154791?hl=en&ref_topic=3293696

Great tutorial with video from Martin Shervington about the Google+ for business:

http://www.martinshervington.com/google-plus-pages-for-business-and-brands/

I hope these are helpful!