# How do you post to a Google+ Page as that page?

Tags: google-plus-pages

You used to be able to click "manage this page", but Google has removed that. Then you had to go to "Google My Business" and you could edit your pages from there, but now Google has removed that as well. How do we edit our Google+ Pages now?

Comment: Ale: yes, it is the same question (as I mentioned in my comment there), but that question is locked and all the answers are wrong, so the only option I had was to post a duplicate question with the correct answer here. I would suggest unlocking that question so I can post my answer there, as having this duplicates seems silly and wasteful.

Comment: I did unprotect the other question. I also updated my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you now have to click on your user picture (the little user icon at the very top-right) when viewing your google+ page, then choose the "brand account" in the dropdown and you will be able to post as the page itself.